# Ideas for reversing strings in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm very new to SML, and have some background in C/C++. I've been trying to write a function called reverseString, which receives a string to reverse. Pretty straightforward. Using an auxiliary function, I was able to write a function which reverses any given string, with an extra character added to the result. For example:

```
- reverseString("hello");
val it = "ollehh" : string
```

Any help with how to overcome this obstacle will be extremely helpful. Please keep in mind that I'm trying to implement the function without any additional function (that is, functions which haven't been used in my broken implementation):

```
fun reverseAux(s:string, i:int) : string = 
    if i = 0 then str(String.sub(s, 0)) 
    else str(String.sub(s, i-1)) ^ reverseAux(s, i-1);

fun reverseString(s:string) : string = 
    reverseAux(s, size(s));
```

Comment: The easiest modification to attain the functionality you are seeking is by changing `i=0` to `i=1` or by changing `size(s)` to `size(s)-1`

Comment: `String.sub(s, 0)` occurs twice in the result, although one of the times it's disguised as `String.sub(s, i-1)` when `i ` is 1.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin and molbdnilo. That's what I was looking for. Using recursion to reverse a string had me quite confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment, this is an easier solution once you know about pattern matching:

```
fun helper [] = []
| helper [x] = [x]
| helper (l::ls) = (helper ls) @ [l];

fun reverse s = implode (helper (explode s));
```

`explode` and `implode` are functions that respectively convert a `string` into a `char list` and vice versa. A list is easier to traverse than a string.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer (which deserves to be accepted) explains how you could do it from scratch -- which is an excellent idea when you are starting out, but it involves `@` which is a somewhat expensive operation (see [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) for an excellent discussion of how seemingly linear algorithms can be quadratic under the hood). There is a way to avoid it, though explaining it is a bit involved (Google "tail recursive reverse" if you are interested). Instead, the built-in function `rev` already implements an efficient list reversal. Using it, together with the built-in composition operator `o` can allow `reverseString` to be created in one line:

```
val reverseString = implode o rev o explode;
```

Note that I used `val` rather than `fun`. Composition is a higher order function which returns other functions, and I am *using* composition to directly create the function I want rather than defining it from scratch. The ability to pack a lot into a single line of code is one of the chief advantages of functional programming. In this case it uses that composition is a chaining operator and is read from right to left. It say that to reverse a string you should first explode it into a list, then reverse the lift, then implode it back into a string.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do *explode*, then *foldl* and then *implode*:

```
fun reverse s = implode (foldl op:: [] (explode s));
```